# qt 4.8.2 qstring char comparison operator error

Tags: qt, kde-plasma

When compiling kdepimlibs on windows using msvc 2010 I get the following error

```
q:\kdepimlibs\akonadi\notes\noteutils.cpp(212) : error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const QString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
        could be 'built-in C++ operator==(const char [8], const char [8])'
        r:\include\QtCore/qchar.h(392): or       'bool operator ==(QChar,QChar)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(908): or       'bool operator ==(QString::Null,QString::Null)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(909): or       'bool operator ==(QString::Null,const QString &)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(910): or       'bool operator ==(const QString &,QString::Null)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(1202): or       'bool operator ==(const QStringRef &,const QStringRef &)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(1205): or       'bool operator ==(const QString &,const QStringRef &)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(1208): or       'bool operator ==(const QStringRef &,const QString &)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(1212): or       'bool operator ==(const QLatin1String &,const QStringRef &)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(1215): or       'bool operator ==(const QStringRef &,const QLatin1String &)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(1236): or       'bool operator ==(const char *,const QStringRef &)'
        r:\include\QtCore/qstring.h(1238): or       'bool operator ==(const QStringRef &,const char *)'
```

(I have trimmed out some suggestions as irrelevant)

the code this is failing on is...

```
#define CLASSIFICATION_PRIVATE "Private"
#define CLASSIFICATION_CONFIDENTIAL "Confidential"
if (KMime::Headers::Base *classificationHeader = msg->headerByType(X_NOTES_CLASSIFICATION_HEADER)) {
    const QString &c = classificationHeader->asUnicodeString();
    if ( c == CLASSIFICATION_PRIVATE ) { **<== HERE**
      classification = Private;
    } else if ( c == CLASSIFICATION_CONFIDENTIAL ) { **<== ALSO HERE**
      classification = Confidential;
    }
  }
```

I cannot find the correct comparison operator. Where should I be looking?
Was it introduced in a later qt?

Comment: Have you tried `if (CLASSIFICATION_PRIVATE == c)` or `QString::compare()`?

Comment: Also, have you tried `QString c = classificationHeader->asUnicodeString();`, i.e. with const (and reference)? Does it work with later versions of Qt though?

Comment: @Laszlo I am compiling kdepimlibs so I don't want to edit it if its not necessary. I am assuming its my mistake. I haven't tried a later version of QT. I was hoping to shortcut the many hours required if its a simple fix.

Comment: Why don't you test this short snippet in a simple main.cpp and see if that works? If that does not work, it is probably your environment caussing it; otherwise kdepimlibs or something else?

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. There is a #define QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII which removes the cast (as it plainly says). A patch was introduced into kdepimlibs 4.10.5 I am compiling that now lets see what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved

It seems to apply to compiling kdepimlibs with msvc2010 (mingw is ok but fails else where)

The problem is QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII  is defined.

There was a patch that was meant for the 4.10.2 tag of the 4.10 branch but it never seemed to have been added to the repository

The patch can be found here https://bugs.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=79049

Apply the patch to the KDE/4.10 branch and it will compile

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Funk seems to have fixed the issue in upstream:

[Make compile on MSVC2010](https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/113855/)

Please make sure you have this patch distributed on your machine.

Comment: Thanks. I was composing my own answer when I saw your reply popup. The fix you mention I finally found as well was pushed into master. as I am compiling from KDE/4.10 I cant use it.